# hiding a layout onClicking a button

Tags: android

How to hide a layout on a button click. Below is my layout. onClicking the search button i need to hide the home layout and display the search layout and vise versa.

```
<com.bibliotheque.android.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444488"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/home_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/search_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mybooks_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/mybooks_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/contact_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/about_btn_label" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/bookList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />           

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.bibliotheque.android.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer>
```

I tried as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener{
    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
    FlyOutContainer root;
    private ListView lv;
    Button home,search,mybooks,contact,about;
    View home_layout,search_layout,mybooks_layout,contact_layout,about_layout;
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ViewGroup content;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
        home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
        mybooks=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybooks_btn);
        contact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.contact_btn);
        about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.about_btn);

        home_layout=findViewById(R.id.home);
        search_layout=findViewById(R.id.search_layout);
        //mybooks_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mybooks_layout);
        //contact_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contact_layout);
        //about_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.about_layout);


        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
        this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sample, null);
        this.setContentView(root);
        inputSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchInput);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.bookList);

        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.book_list_item, R.id.book_item, products);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void toggleMenu(View v){
        Log.i("Toggle method", "Toggle Method");
        home_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // not working
        this.root.toggleMenu();
    }
    public enum MenuState {
        CLOSED, OPEN, CLOSING, OPENING
    };
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {

        switch (direction) {

          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : 
              if(this.root.menuCurrentState==com.bibliotheque.android.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer.MenuState.CLOSED){
                  try{

                         this.root.toggleMenu();  
                     }catch(Exception e){
                         Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }  
              }
          break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : 
              if(this.root.menuCurrentState==com.bibliotheque.android.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer.MenuState.OPEN){
                 try{
                     this.root.toggleMenu();  
                 }catch(Exception e){
                     //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
              }

          break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  
                                                         break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    
                                                         break;

          } 
           //Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
           this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
          return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me); 
         }
    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

setVisibility(View.GONE) in toggleMenu method is never called or not working. How can 
I Hide that layout?

I am trying this same code in my another basic application and it is working fine but not working here.:( I am unable to figure out the problem. Please Help me Out.

Comment: Is the home layout vanishing?

Comment: Instead of layout try to make the views visible or Invisible.

Comment: @Biplab tried both but nothing happens

Comment: Is your `onClick()` method actually getting called?  Verify via the debugger.  It will work to change the visibility of a `ViewGroup` in order to remove all children from view as well.

Comment: the XMl code that u have provided, in that all layouts have width and height as match parent. so try out by giving  giving some height in dp

Comment: @Biplab tried with dp but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You're not telling your layout to disappear with:

```
home.setVisibility(View.GONE);//not working
```

but instead a button referenced by:

```
home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
```

Comment: Sorry I was testing with button and forget to change the code. Anyways even the button also not disappearing. I changed that line in my question..

Comment: It doesn't look like you've even actually hidden the other layout, but when you toggle layouts, it's a good plan to use the pattern "Hide all that should be hidden and make visible all that should be seen." So in your case, try adding in search_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why would you use Layout hiding/showing instead of Dialog boxes (assuming you wish to bring up Search box to type search criteria) but anyways, just tried quick basic button click -> toggle layouts.

home_ly is standard layout that needs to be shown on loading activity.
new_ly is new layout that you wish to be loaded. Set this to be hidden by default.

```
private void ChangeLayout(){
    LinearLayout home_ly = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.home_layout);
    LinearLayout new_ly = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.new_layout);
    if(home_ly.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && new_ly.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
        home_ly.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        new_ly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(home_ly.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && new_ly.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        home_ly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new_ly.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        home_ly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new_ly.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    }
```

This goes into oncreate:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.change);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ChangeLayout();

            }
        });
```